# Best ASP.net WYSIWYG

Tags: asp.net, wysiwyg

Ok, 
i've read most relevant questions asked here previously on this but I still don't see a clear "best in class" suggestion for WYSIWYG editors for ASP.net

I've used fckeditor up to now (found it ok but many problems with config/permissions on folder etc.).

I'm looking for something that has a lot of flexibility/config options and can integrate nicely with the sites css.

Also i'd like something that minimises config requirements when moving from server to server etc.

Any good suggestions are much appreciated.

Ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we use the Telerik Radeditor, and it performs great.  Microsoft also uses it on their MSDN website.  It's not free, but worth the investment.

**http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx**

Comment: The whole suite of Telerik controls are fantastic!

Comment: Thanks Nathan, i've used this within MCMS a few years ago - will try the standalone version - looks pricey though!

Answer (score 4):

Almost didn't open the question because I thought it would have been mentioned already, but [FCKEditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/) is a great freely available WYSIWYG editor with a good team behind it.

Answer (score 3):

[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) - besides beeing configurable and extendable, it's quite nice to integrate with asp.net (or any other web framework) since it's just javascript over a textarea

Answer (score 2):

I stopped using the freetextbox control because I don't like the code that comes with it. I found Cute Editor for ASP.NET to be the best solution.

Demo:

http://cutesoft.net/example/general.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try Free Text Box [Free Text Box](http://freetextbox.com/) as well. A lot less hassle than fckeditor  i've found

Comment: I always find it amusing that complete FreeTextBox is not 'free' ;).. Anyway, FreeTextBox is a good choice!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what budget you're working with, but it might be worth taking a look at Dreamweaver CS3+. It has support for ASP.NET and its WYSIWYG is quite good.

Comment: heh - dude, that's not what he ment. he ment a WYSIWIG editor which he can embed inside a webpage .. not a program to make webpages.

Comment: oh heh. my bad. i guess thats what happens when you try to answer a question pre-coffee